# Cutting out outstanding View

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a custom view, where I have a Button which I want to be the same shape as the Superview. So I created a View with rounded corners. There I want a button on the bottom of the View and having the corners cut out at the same point as the superview.

[image: Idea]

I hope this Image gives an Idea of what I mean.
Which attributes does the button need to be get the same shape as the superview. Also here the code if it helps.

```
let button: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Buy", for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
    //button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
    button.backgroundColor = .gray
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    return button
}()
func show(){

    self.addSubview(background)
    self.addSubview(overview)
    background.frame = self.frame
    background.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(close)))
    overview.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 40, width: self.frame.width-80, height: self.frame.height-80)
    let size = overview.frame


    overview.addSubview(button)
    let imageHeight = size.height/3


    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: size.height-38, width: size.width, height: 38)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.background.alpha = 1
        self.overview.alpha = 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "**clipsToBounds**" property to the superView(I hope the cornered white background view is overview property) like follows,

```
overview.clipsToBounds = true
```

This will make its subview appear with cornered view.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `clipsToBounds = true` on the view that contains the button. That should make it clip the button.

Failing that you might need to build a mask for the button that's rounded on the bottom corners but not the top. (You could use the UIBezierPath method `init(roundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii:)` to create a bezier path with only the bottom corners rounded, and install that as the path of a CAShapeLayer, and install THAT as the mask layer for your button.)